# Why do I get a make: *** No target specified and no makefile error?

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to use make, but I get `make: *** target not specified and no makefile.`

An error message saying Stopped occurred.

I used the ./configure command in the terminal, but `./configure : The term './configure' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.`

An error appears. What should I do?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJt8q.png)

Comment: Install [MSYS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30069830/how-can-i-install-mingw-w64-and-msys2), install `make` in it. Run `./configure` and make inside MSYS2 terminal.

Comment: We can't know what you are trying to do or what you have done so far. Apparently you are trying to install something; but what, where, how? Usually `./configure` is run _before_ `make` and only then will the `Makefile` exist. But if it doesn't exist, we can't know why. Did you forget to download the software whose installation instructions you are trying to follow? Or forget to extract the files? Or did you forget to `cd` into the directory where you extracted those files? See also the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask) as well as the guidance for providing a [mre].

Comment: @tripleee And, as `./configure` is a sh shell script, it wouldn't run in powershell in the first place.